# Can we Scale gRPC like worker processes in the same server

Tags: grpc, supervisord

Our application is expected to receive thousands of request every second and we are considering gRPC as one of our main service is in a different language.
My queries are

1. Can we use something like supervisor to spawn multiple workers (one gRPC server per service) as gRPC servers listening to the same port, Or is gRPC servers limited to only one per server/port
2. How would i go about the performance testing to determine maximum requests per gRPC server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. While you can certainly use supervisord to spawn multiple gRPC server processes, port sharing would be a problem. However, this is a Posix limitation, not a gRPC limitation. By default, multiple processes cannot listen on the same port. (to be clear, multiple processes can bind to the same port with SO_REUSEPORT, but this would not result in the behavior you presumably want).

So you have two options in order to get traffic routed to the proper service on a single port. The first option is to run all of the gRPC services in the same process and attached to the same server.

If having only a single server process won't work for you, then you'll have to start looking at load balancing. You'd front all of your services with any HTTP/2-capable load balancer (e.g. Envoy, Nginx) and have it listen on your single desired port and route to each gRPC server process as appropriate.

2. This is a very broad question. The answer is "the way you'd benchmark any non-gRPC server." [This site](https://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/%7Egernot/benchmarking-crimes.html) is a great resource for some principles behind benchmarking.